# Does the following code invoke Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#define max(x,y) (x)>(y)? (x): (y)

int main() {
  int i = 10;
  int j = 5;
  int k = 0;
  k = max(i++,++j);
  std::cout << i << "\t" << j << "\t" << k << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `max` macro is actually a `min` macro.

Comment: @James, The macro is expanding in a way that may be causing two modifications to the same variable. Two modifictaions to the same variable without a sequence point between them is UB, I think. I don't know enough about sequence points to be sure if operator ?: introduce a sequence point or not.

Comment: Maybe it's not undefined, but is it clear?

Comment: @kyoryu: No. I know that it is absolutely bad practice to use macros for this sort of thing. Actually this question was asked in round 1 of some local coding contest and I marked UB as answer. :(

Comment: @Rahul G: In terms of clarity, the macro is probably the least offensive thing :)

Comment: @kyoryu: Ever since I have read this (http://bit.ly/9WemNk), I do not use macros for anything except as header guards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

In this case the situation is saved by the fact the `?:` operator has a *sequence point* immediately after evaluating the first operand (the condition) and after that only one of the two expressions (second or third operand) is evaluated. Your code is equivalent to

```
...
bool c = i++ > ++j;
k = c ? i++ : ++j;
...
```

No undefined behavior here.

Comment: Indeed, without a sequence point the consequent could be evaluated at the same time as the condition; then we would see side effects for consequents (or alternates) that weren't used.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there certainly are a lot of problems with it.

- max is actually computing min
- increment operators are doubled on whatever choice is selected since you are using a macro
- using postfix/prefix increments is just thrown in to confuse, but doesn't have a lot of bearing on the problem.

This code will produce the same results each time run, so no, it's not undefined.  At the cout:

```
i = 11
k = 7
j = 7
```

This sounds like a bad homework problem. :)

Comment: Are you kidding, it looks like a good homework problem to me. What does this do? Why?

Comment: Well, that is why i put the smiley face on that one.  Mostly since it wasn't tagged "homework". :)

Comment: No, it's not a homework question. This was asked in first round of a local coding contest and I marked UB as answer. :(

Comment: Yes, I could believe that, thanks for sharing.  I like questions like this, short and fun to work through, even if I get them wrong sometimes!